# ng-content in form tag

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-ngcontent

I have a form component with `<ng-content>` tag inside and btn that currently does nothing. Also I have a parent component that use it with simple input as content projection.

The problem is, whenever I click on the button, both parent and form-component are reloads, and the page refresh with the initial state.

**formComponent.html:**

```
<form class="form-control">
   <div class="form-group">
     <ng-content></ng-content>
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

**parentComponent.html:**

```
<app-form-component>
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="car.id">
</app-form-component>
```

I feel like I'm miss something basic with content-projection.

sackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zqjxjs

Comment: Can't you remove it if that does nothing?

Comment: @Justcode I wanted to perform emit but then I notice this behvior.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz example to reproduce problem?

Comment: @Justcode sackblitz added
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zqjxjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for suggestion, The problem is you have declared button type as **submit**

```
 <button type="submit">Search</button>
```

So, If you declared button type as submit it will submit the form like this.
I have also faced this type of problem. So just replace,

html file

```
  <button type="button" (click)="doLogic()">Search</button>
```

ts file

```
doLogic(){
   //do your logics here.
}
```

I hope its solve your problem. Lets try this once and let me know.

Thanks,

Muthukumar

Comment: @Muthukumar thanks that solve it! but I notice somting strange; 
so why if I use: type="submit"  **without** content-projection it doesn't reload my page?

Comment: Thats basic things of an forms button and submit.

Comment: Please change like this and use. Please mark as answer if your problem has been solved.

Comment: I just notice that I forgot to import FormsModule. so type submit not realoading the page also.